# Printing text like conversations between persons

Tags: python

Is it possible to print text in python like conversation?

I have a text file having story with conversation between multiple characters.

Text in other file:

> Guru holds up two fingers.
>
> Guru: Two men come down a chimney. One comes out with a clean face,
> the other comes out with a dirty face. Which one washes his face.
>
> The young man stares at the Guru.
>
> Young Man: Is that really a test in logic.
>
> The Guru nods.
>
> Young Man: The one with the dirty face washes his face - he answers
> confidently.
>
> Guru: Wrong. The one with the clean face washes his face. Examine the
> logic. The one with the dirty face looks at the one with the clean
> face and thinks his face is clean. The one with the clean face looks
> at the one with the dirty face and thinks his face is dirty. So, the
> one with the clean face washes his face.
>
> Young man: Very clever,. Give me another test.
>
> The Guru again holds up two fingers.
>
> Guru: Two men come down a chimney. One comes out with a clean face,
> the other comes out with a dirty face. Which one washes his face.
>
> Young man: We have already established that. The one with the clean
> face washes his face.

My code:

```
import time

print("This is the story i am telling.")

def storytelling():
    with open('story.txt', 'r+') as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            print(line, time.sleep(0.15))

storytelling()
```

Result:

```
This is the story I am telling.
Guru holds up two fingers.
 None
Guru: Two men come down a chimney. One comes out with a clean face, the other comes out with a dirty face. Which one washes his face.
 None
The young man stares at the Guru.
 None
Young Man: Is that really a test in logic.
 None
The Guru nods.
 None
```

**I will try to find how to get rid of None in the result later**

The above text may be like a para or as person by person conversation.
using `def conversation():` function, because its for next use.
The printing must be like A saying his story line or para and there is time delay so user can read the lines and after that B saying his story line and a time delay for user to read it and so on.

I tried to use `.readlines()` but it's not useful. It's reading line by line but I want to read person by person. I can workout on time delay between text to text but how can break the text between person by person.

Comment: Please add some code that you have tried. Stackoverflow is not a free code writing service. I will put the answer soon after you put what you have tried

Comment: Updated my question. Dont know how to reply to your comment.

Comment: You are printing the result of `time.sleep` which is `None`. Change to `print(line) ; time.sleep(0.15)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get rid of the `None` you have to remove the `time.sleep(0.15)` that you have inside the `print`

It must look like this:

```
from time import sleep

print("This is the story i am telling.")

def storytelling():
    with open('story.txt', 'r+') as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            print(line)
            sleep(0.15)

storytelling()
```

But in my case you don't need the `f.readline()` . It will work also with the following code:

```
for line in f:
    print(line)
    sleep(0.15)
```

If you want to `read` person by person i can think only 2 solutions with my imagination. The 1st is to create a .txt file with the dialogues like this:

```
R
Guru holds up two fingers.
G
Guru: Two men come down a chimney. One comes out with a clean face, the other comes out with a dirty face. Which one washes his face. The young man stares at the Guru.
Y
Young Man: Is that really a test in logic.
R
The Guru nods.
Y
Young Man: The one with the dirty face washes his face
R
- he answers confidently.
G
Guru: Wrong. The one with the clean face washes his face. Examine the logic. The one with the dirty face looks at the one with the clean face and thinks his face is clean. The one with the clean face looks at the one with the dirty face and thinks his face is dirty. So, the one with the clean face washes his face.
Y
Young man: Very clever,. Give me another test.
R
The Guru again holds up two fingers.
G
Guru: Two men come down a chimney. One comes out with a clean face, the other comes out with a dirty face. Which one washes his face.
Y
Young man: We have already established that. The one with the clean face washes his face.
```

and then with the `f.readline()` to read the dialogues and see that if `f.readline() == 'R'` then `print` . You get the point.

The 2rd solution is to create 4-5 .txt files with the dialogues from every person and combine the code to pick the dialogues between them.

If you have more questions feel free to ask. Type one the comments `@bilakos` and i will get a notify

Comment: A 3rd solution would be to read the file and save each line to a list `guru` or `man` respectively and then just print those lists...

Comment: @Tomerikoo Yes, but those lists will have the full length of the dialogues just for one person... i mean everything that the ```guru``` have to say will be printed and the same to the ```young man```.  Am I missing something?

Comment: No but that's exactly what the OP wants. Am ***I*** missing something?

Comment: @Tomerikoo maybe with a better explanation from the OP we weren't dealing with this ;)

Comment: @Tomerikoo I will try to use all of them. I will also try to take input from user. According to Youngman / User answer the guru will reply him (Not like chat bot). I just trigger the answer with user input (Say just like in sims games). That my next step.